# Direct link to a subfolder view returns 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, view, subdirectory

I cannot directly load a view that is in a subfolder in my CodeIgniter `views` folder with a direct link.

Here is the folder structure:

```
my_project/
    application/
        views/
            pages/
                about.php
                about/
                    organization.php
                    history.php
```

I need to access `organization.php` and `history.php` through a link such as:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo base_url('about'); ?>'>About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo base_url('about/organization'); ?>'>About/Organization</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href='<?php echo base_url('about/history'); ?>'>About/History</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However I get a 404.

My `htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /my_project/

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /my_project/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_project/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Here is my `routes.php` that directs to my default view controller `Pages::view(path/to/file)`:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['pages/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = strtoupper(str_replace(["-", "–"], ' ', $page));
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE** whenever I directly use

```
$this->load->view('pages/views/about/organization');
```

it is okay. Same with printing:

```
file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/about/organization.php');
```

I don't know what could have messed this up.

**Do I have to make a custom controller just for these subfolders?** This is the only solution I can think of  right now.

---

**NOTE** I also set this subfolder's (the entire project's actually) permissions to `777` and the direct link still did not work.

---

**NOTE** My only solution right now is to make *separate* controllers for each of these subfolders just to view them! Is this really impossible to do with just one controller?

Like the url pattern `my_app/controller/method` is strict and `my_app/folder/view` is not allowed unless `folder` and `view` corresponds to a `controller` and `method` respectively?

---

**SOLUTION**

## [Zeeshan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469750/zeeshan) [did](http://66.media.tumblr.com/f19127770632190559739b5b3fa5c2fd/tumblr_inline_nzp01iXO3M1sb92kb_500.gif) [that](http://media.giphy.com/media/bxqnPHvJaAdMc/giphy.gif)!

Shantay, you stay! [Thank you](http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m0yek3BbZE1qc8ie7o2_250.gif).

You are correct, I was going for a **generic** method to catch all my static page view requests. We can close this issue now (I will award the bounty in 20 hours).

[You were the only one who understood the assignment](http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/243e6d9d-b7e1-4e77-8363-7fecd39b95a3/ba0a1dc4-bea5-42d7-8656-0641a6a28cf8.gif).

Comment: Guys I do not want to create multiple controllers for each of these subfolders please help I know in my heart this is possible with this one controller maybe my `htaccess`???

Comment: Your routes.php file is not well written. Read [this](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html) again. **The reserved routes must come before any wildcard or regular expression routes.** but also **Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.** meaning if you have `$route['(:any)'] = 'something/here'` it must come as last line in file.

Comment: @Tpojka: I followed your advice and still no changes. [I get a 404 for the subfolder view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360697/link-to-view-inside-subfolder-does-not-display-correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through your question,i found that you are trying to write some generic function that will take care of loading your views.Please refer below as you can handle any structure in codeigniter.

Controller function will go like this

```
public function view($folder='',$page = 'home')
{       
    $path = $folder!=""?$folder.'/':'';
    $path = $page!=""?$path.$page:$page;

    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    **$this->load->view($path, $data);**
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

Now in your views the link will go like this:

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href='<?php echo base_url."about/"; ?>'>About</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='<?php echo base_url."about/organization" ?>'>About/Organization</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href='<?php echo base_url."about/history" ?>'>About/History</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Also please note in Codeigniter you don't need to handle 404 manually.Just add following to show your custom

```
$route['404_override'] = 'mycustom404';//mycustom404 is controller for 404
```

Let me know if you have any doubts or queries.

Regards,
Zeeshan.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU this is **EXACTLY** what I wanted but cannot put into words THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Welcome buddy...Its honor to share what you know.
Feel free to ask your doubts or queries.

Answer (score 0):

I think CodeIgniter's URI pattern is strictly `controller/method` and no love for `subfolder/view_file`.

I just made a controller for `About` with methods `organization` and `history` that will show the page.

```
<?php
class About extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function organization($page = 'organization')
    {
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/about/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = strtoupper(str_replace(["-", "–"], ' ', $page));
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/about/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

    function history($page = 'history')
    {
        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/about/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = strtoupper(str_replace(["-", "–"], ' ', $page));
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/about/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

[I will probably do this for `Contact Us`, `FAQs`...](http://40.media.tumblr.com/cd561a3bd0435fa34b2bb28bbdc932e5/tumblr_inline_ny2r8y5aCy1qfrihj_400.png)

[Apparently this is the correct answer](http://www.zyxware.com/articles/5134/how-can-we-slimply-create-a-static-page-in-codeigniter). Use controllers and methods to show a page with the form `subfolder/view`. WIG.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the `Pages::view()` to not have a default parameter:

```
<?php
class Pages extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function view()
    {
        $page = $this->uri->segment(1);
        if(!empty($this->uri->segment(2))) {
            $page .= '/'.$this->uri->segment(2);
        }

        if(!file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            show_404();
        }

        $data = "";
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}
```

The pages in my site so far have one level of subfolder so I hardcoded the following:

```
$page = $this->uri->segment(1);
if(!empty($this->uri->segment(2))) {
    $page .= '/'.$this->uri->segment(2);
}
```

Given my link `http://localhost:8080/practice/item-2/subitem-2`, the value of the URI segments are as follows:

```
$this->uri->segment(1) == 'item-2'
$this->uri->segment(2) == 'subitem-1'
```

I updated the `routes.php` with hardcoded catchers as well:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

$route['pages/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['pages/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
$route['pages/view/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['pages/view/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['(:any)/(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1/$2';
```