# CodeIgniter make .htaccess return 404 for index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

Here is my `.htaccess` file to "remove `index.php`" from my CodeIgniter project URLs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|media|assets|common|themes|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This managed to *add another way* to navigate URLs other than `index.php` making these URLs both legal:

```
my-project/index.php/home
```

and

```
my-project/home
```

How do I rewrite the `.htaccess` so that all URLs of the pattern

```
my-project/index.php/*
```

will return 404?

Comment: Can I ask why you'd want to do this?  There should be no security risk in allowing somebody to add `index.php` into the URL... if they'd even think to do that for some strange reason.

Comment: @Sparky it just looks ugly to me. Bottom line. Cut and dry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution would be setting `.htacces` rules to redirect all request to URLs without `index.php` in it. Check this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /codeigniter/

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /codeigniter/$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /codeigniter/index.php/$1 [L]
```

*Disclaimer 1. If you are in root directory, leave just `/` everywhere you see `/codeigniter/`.*
*Disclaimer 2. Seems like commented out, but it is up to editor here on site, code would be working for you as is. Just c/p.*

[Credits](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/urls/remove_index.php.html).

Comment: Thank you @Tpojka! Do you mind checking [my other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39303990/direct-link-to-a-subfolder-view-returns-404)? I think it has to do with `.htaccess` as well